# Elastic, mongoosastic why only indexes a part of the collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I use **elastic** on **mongodb** by **mongoosastic**.

My problem is when I do index on a collection. Mongoosastic only indexes a part of the collection (for example, my collection has 50,000 documents but mongoosastic only indexes 3000 of them).

I use this code to generate docs and indexing:

```
var post, 
    count = 0,
    countes = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    post = new BlogPost(req.body)
    post.save(function() {
            count++;
            console.log(count + "\n")
            //res.redirect('/');
            post.on('es-indexed', function() {
              countes++;
              console.log('document' + countes + ' indexed');
            });
    });
```

Comment: when run follow codes returns total :3393   BlogPost.search({query:req.body.q,size:3000}, function(err, results){
    //process.exit(console.log(req.body.q));
    res.send(results);
  });

Comment: you are posting documents one by one? try to create a bulk post

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused as to why you are using `req.body` but what I think you are trying to do is:

```
var stream = BlogPost.synchronize();
var count = 0;

stream.on('data', function(err, doc){
    count++;
});

stream.on('close', function(){
    console.log('indexed ' + count + ' documents!');
    cb(null, 'indexed ' + count + ' documents');
});

stream.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
    cb(err, null);
});
```

This will go though your existing `BlogPost` collection and index all of them.